# Cassandra 2.0+ Performance for Price on Amazon EC2, Google Compute Engine, Rackspace Cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cassandra, google-compute-engine, rackspace-cloud

I recently read this article about Cassandra performance on three large cloud infrastructures (AWS, GCloud, and Rackspace): http://www.stackdriver.com/cassandra-aws-gce-rackspace/

Google has since published an article claiming 1 million writes/sec but using a setup that most people would never use, being 330 nodes.

Following up on that, they have taken the tuning lessons from that exercise and made a Cassandra 2.0 deploy available: http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.com/2014/07/click-to-deploy-apache-cassandra-on-google-compute-engine.html

I'm wondering if anyone has more recent benchmarks taking a mixed IO test or had real world experience with a nearly identical deployments on 2 or all 3 infrastructures. What was your experience? What do you think about price/performance for the given infrastructures? How about more subjective issues such as Cassandra manageability/maintainability on each?